# System out print into text field

Tags: java, javafx

Hello guys I'm trying to put a System.out.printin into an textfield.

Currently my text field is called:

```
TextField tf3 = new TextField();
```

I currently have a working calculator but it prints out the answer in the console and I want it to print it out into the JavaFX application.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
}

public berekenen test123 = new berekenen();

public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
    int x = Integer.parseInt(tf1.getText());
    int y = Integer.parseInt(tf2.getText());
    if (event.getSource() == submitplus) {
        System.out.println(test123.add(x, y));
    }
    if (event.getSource() == submitmin) {
        System.out.println(test123.sub(x, y));
    }
    if (event.getSource() == submitkeer) {
        System.out.println(test123.mult(x, y));
    }
    if (event.getSource() == submitdeel) {
        System.out.println(test123.div(x, y));
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to do this and if this is possible?

Comment: what is the error ? can you post the exception

Comment: `tf3.setText("The string you want to display")`.

Comment: There is no error I just want to know if its possible to put systemourprint into a textfield

Comment: @JavaHackerMan12 you mean you want to print the value of the textfield on the console ?

Comment: @ElarbiMohamedAymen No I can print in into the console and I want it to get inside a textfield

From console > to Textfield in JavaFX

Comment: like @Pagbo said `textfield.setText();`

Comment: @ElarbiMohamedAymen It doesnt work because its an int. I tried this:

System.out.println(test123.add(x, y));
            tf3.setText(test123.add(x, y));

Comment: @JavaHackerMan12 try this `tf3.setText(String.valueOf(test123.add(x, y)));`

Comment: @ElarbiMohamedAymen Thanks that worked

Comment: BTW: Checking multiple buttons as possible sources is bad practice. Better use different event handlers for different buttons, e.g. `submitplus.setOnAction(evt -> setResult(text123.add(getNum1(), getNum2()))); submitmin.setOnAction(evt -> setResult(text123.sub(getNum1(), getNum2())));` Where `getNum1()` and `getNum2()` return the numbers from `tf1` and `tf2` converted to `int` respectively and `setResult` writes the output to `tf3`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to use `TextField.setText(String str)` you have to cast your `int` value to a `String` to do that you can use `String.valueOf(int i)` so your code will be like this :

```
tf3.setText(String.valueOf(test123.add(x, y)));
```